# Why $A=\int^1_0xdx-\int^1_0x^2dx$ is not the same as measuring the line integral of $\int_\mathcal{C}f(x)ds=\int^1_0x\sqrt{1+4x^2}$?

Tags: vector-fields, line-integrals

Today I started learning about line integrals and I have a doubt about the concept itself of the line integral.

As I understood, measuring the line integral was the sum of the $ds$ elements multiplied by the function. So I thought of using this concept to measure the area between the function $x$ and $x^2$ in the interval $[0, 1]$.

This Area is $\int^1_0xdx-\int^1_0x^2dx=\frac{1}{6}$

But when I compute this with the line integral method gives me something different, I thought of this Area as
$$
\int_\mathcal{C}f(x)ds
$$
which is the sum of the arc length element (which would be the arc length element of $x^2$) multiplied by the function. But computing this gives a different result
$$
\int_\mathcal{C}f(x)ds=\int^1_0x\sqrt{1+4x^2}dx\approx0.95
$$

I am obviously misunderstanding something, but I couldn't find what it is.

I would appreciate any help

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear what you are trying to do. What is the contour $C$, and what is the function $f(x)$?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The line, $\mathcal{C}$, in which I am trying to find the integral is $x^2$, and the function is $f(x)=x$. So the line integral is $\int^1_0\underbrace{x}_{f(x)}\times\underbrace{\sqrt{1+4x^2}dx}_{ds}$. So basically the question is, If this integral is the sum of the arc length element of $x^2$ multiplied by the function $f(x)=x$, why is not the same as the area between this two functions?. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: your integral function most probably always needs to be in physical units of [/m] so [Kg/m] and doing the line integral gives you Kg, a famous example of calculating mass of a thin rope

Comment: Your line integral formula does not make sense. What if you try to measure the area from $0$? Would you use $f(x)=0$? then the integral vanishes. The best way to think about integrals is as a sum. So $\sqrt{1+4x^2}dx$ is a length element along the $x^2$ curve. What figure has area $x\sqrt{1+4x^2}dx$?